# Simple pendulum simulation, result doesn't match reality, can't find the error

Tags: python, numpy, simulation

I was watching on youtube the channel of 3Blue1Brown (Overview of differential equations | Chapter 1).
The video is talking about simulating a pendulum, I tried to code that but strange results appears.
I basically copied the code from the video and added just a little more things.

====
I'm trying to simulate this differential equation:
This is math notation not programming :)
theta_double_dot = -mu * theta_dot - (g / L) * sin(theta)

Meanings:
theta := angle, theta_dot := angular speed, theta_double dot := angular acceleration, mu := air friction constant, g := gravitational constant, L := Length of pendulum

delta_t := is the time step

====

Initial conditions:
theta := 60 degrees, theta_dot := 0 velocity

Problem 1:
test1 with values:
g = 9.8, L = 2, mu = 0.09, delta_t = 0.01
result: accelerating perpetual motion free energy 4 everybody :)

test2 with values:
g = 9.8, L = 2, mu = 0.01 (Less air friction than test above), delta_t = 0.01
result: this is the more realistic

more air resistance, more the system tend to perpetual motion and free energy gain?!

Problem 2:
whatever values I chose for calling `theta(..some value here..)` the simulation ALWAYS ends with the same values.

Problem 3: (some extra): How can I make the code faster?
I think the operation of append are really costly because is has to copy every time the array.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Physical constants
g = 9.8
L = 2
mu = 0.1

# Initial conditions
THETA_0 = np.pi / 3  # 60 degrees
THETA_DOT_0 = 0  # No initial angual velocity

theta_values = np.array([])
theta_dot_values = np.array([])
theta_double_dot_values = np.array([])

# Definition of ODE
def get_theta_double_dot(theta, theta_dot):
    return -mu * theta_dot - (g / L) * np.sin(theta)


def print_graph(t, delta_t):
    plt.plot(np.arange(0, t, delta_t), theta_values, label='theta')
    plt.plot(np.arange(0, t, delta_t), theta_dot_values, label='theta_dot')
    plt.plot(np.arange(0, t, delta_t), theta_double_dot_values, label='theta_double_dot')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

# Solution to the differential equation
def theta(t):
    # Initialize changing values
    global theta_values
    global theta_dot_values
    global theta_double_dot_values

    theta = THETA_0
    theta_dot = THETA_DOT_0
    delta_t = 0.001  # Some time step

    for time in np.arange(0, t, delta_t):
        theta_double_dot = get_theta_double_dot(theta, theta_dot)

        #  saving values into arrays, this is for printing results
        theta_values = np.append(theta, theta_values)
        theta_dot_values = np.append(theta_dot, theta_dot_values)
        theta_double_dot_values = np.append(theta_double_dot, theta_double_dot_values)

        # updating thetas values
        theta += theta_dot * delta_t
        theta_dot += theta_double_dot * delta_t

    print_graph(t, delta_t)
    return theta

theta(15)
```

Comment: You are using [Euler's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method), a *theoretically* important method for approximating solutions to differential equations.  The problem with Euler's method is that it requires very small time steps to generate a reasonably accurate solution--but if the steps are *too* small, the calculation can suffer from inaccuracy from the loss of numerical precision.  If you are specifically interested in learning about Euler's method, then this is a great exercise (try different values of `delta_t`).

Comment: Why is `matlab` tagged here? This question has nothing to do with MATLAB

Comment: On the other hand, if you are more interested in modeling the dynamics of the pendulum, then you'll probaby want to use a better numerical solver.  Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56153628/using-scipys-solve-ivp-to-solve-non-linear-pendulum-motion) for someone else's experiments with solving these equations.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser yeah, I tried with even smaller delta_t but it takes ages and the result is still not even close to reality.

Comment: @SardarUsama I tough lot of people who works with dynamic systems happens to work with matlab, so more chance to find someone with very good answers :)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser changing delta_t maybe can explain the strange behave, but not the fact that whatever time i chose for the simulation it always ends with the same values, this is even more strange.

Comment: When I run the code as it is, I see an oscillation with a growing amplitude.  That's because you save the values like this: `theta_values = np.append(theta, theta_values)`.  You are putting the new `theta` value at the *beginning* of the array.  So your plot actually shows the solution reversed in time.

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works. You cannot just add any tag based on such assumptions

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser omg thx Warren that explains all the weird stuff... thx :))